# Dell OpenManage iDrac

Tags: dell, drac

I have installed OpenManage Essentials on a Windows 7 workstation with the assumption that nothing needed to be done on the actual server I am trying to manage. The server has an iDrac v7 component and I was under the impression that OpenManage just connects to that?

When I try to connect I put the IP address of the iDrac console and the username/password and I get a 'Connection Error' message.

So my question, does OpenManage Server Administrator have to be installed on the server that is to be managed, even if it has a DRAC connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question, yes, you do require the OpenaManage service be installed on each server you wish to manage.

Answer (score 1):

To access iDrac from the host OS, you either need:

- to activate "OS to idrac pass-through".   See http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/5097.os-to-idrac-pass-through-using-idrac7.aspx
- to configure host IP and iDrac IP on different subnets.
- or to use the dedicated NIC (iDrac Enterprise only).

Installing OpenManage Server Administrator is not mandatory for most features.

Comment: I am trying to manage a remote server with OpenManage, the question was regarding the required installation of OpenManage on the remote server or if OpenManage can utilise management functions remotely from the iDrac alone.

Comment: OMSA does not connect to remote idrac. OMSA is the agent that supplement or replace the idrac. If your looking for a tools to centrally manage servers with idrac, have a look at "OpenManage Essential".

Comment: I had installed OpenManage Essentials as part of the implementation but it looks like it still requires OMSA installed on each host, I simply can't get it to connect to the iDrac at all, though this may just be an implementation issue. I guess that's what I was trying to confirm, I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: OME can connect to either OMSA (host IP) or iDrac (iDrac IP) with WS-MAN protocol. Futhermore, OME has a "remote task" to deploy OMSA to multiple servers.

Comment: After more playing around it seemed it was just an implementation problem on my part, OME was able to monitor through the iDrac